# METADATA and METADATA.jl: what are the differences?

Tags: julia

After reading the manual, I'm still unclear as to these two things. Both are directories, although the `.jl` makes you think one is a Julia source file, it's not, it's a directory. Both seem to have similar content:

```
$ head METADATA.jl/README.md
This is the official METADATA repo for the Julia package manager. See [manual section](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/packages/) on packages for how to use the package manager to install and develop packages.

...

$ head METADATA/README.md
This is the official METADATA repo for the Julia package manager. See [manual section](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/packages/) on packages for how to use the package manager to install and develop packages.
```

The documentation says things like:

> Fork the main METADATA repository

or

> Cloning METADATA from git://github.com/JuliaLang/METADATA.jl

and uses examples such as:

```
git remote add USERNAME https://github.com/USERNAME/METADATA.jl.git
                                                             ^^
```

and

```
cd ~/.julia/v0.5/METADATA
```

So I've got myself confused by the terminology, because the documentation seems to switch between METADATA with and without `.jl`.

Comment: I don't think it's normal to have a directory on disk called "METADATA.jl". You should typically only have a "METADATA" directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Roughly speaking, they are the same thing. On Github, the suffix `.jl` emphasizes this repo is a julia **package**, which is a name convention. In general, a normal folder name doesn't include any suffix, so the `METADATA.jl` on Github becomes the `METADATA` in local machine.

Comment: Your answer seems good. I think I must have cloned it and not wanted to replace the original, hence giving it another name. It's very confusing...

Answer (score 2):

Most Julia packages have a `.jl` in the name, but in your library folder `.julia/v0.x/`, they don't. For example, you may have a folder like `Plots` in there for `Plots.jl`, etc. So they are the same thing: `METADATA` is the folder in the library for the `METADATA.jl` repository.